# ReactJS code as jsFiddle has syntax errors

Tags: reactjs, jsfiddle

There is something about jsFiddle an React that I don't understand. Based on my best guess I have a component defined as

```
class MakeWorkers extends React.Component {

render() {
    return (<ul>this.props.people.map((person) => {
        const { name, whatCanDo } = person;
            return (<li key={name}>My name is {name}, I can do {whatCanDo}</li>);    
    })</ul>);
  }
}

const people = [
  { name: 'Josh', whatCanDo: 'painting' },
  { name: 'Lay', whatCanDo: 'security' },
  { name: 'Ralph', whatCanDo: 'cleaning' }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <MakeWorkers people={people}/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

This seems like valid JSX syntax to me but when I put it into a Fiddle in jsFiddle it doesn't work and there are a number of syntax errors in the render function. I am not sure what I am missing in getting this simple example of mapping and JSX working in jsFiddle. One of the main error messages is that jsFiddle claims there is an unterminated regular expression. Something is very confused. Maybe I am not including the right libraries? The full Fiddle is [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rkevinburton/9nLwxhma/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you forgot to wrap the content inside `<ul>` with `{}`. You can find the edited code here: https://jsfiddle.net/5e9ayd12/

The editor complains the same thing. Even the boilerplate code has the same syntax error. So I bed it's a bug.
https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx

Answer (score 0):

Not valid JSX, this is valid:

```
class MakeWorkers extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.people.map(person => {
          const { name, whatCanDo } = person;
          return (
            <li key={name}>
              My name is {name}, I can do {whatCanDo}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

`this.props.people.map` is javascript expression need to be inside `{}`

you can found more doc [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained what was changed to make the JSX valid.